# Why can't Rhythmbox play most of the files from my mt-daap share?

Tags: ubuntu, music, rhythmbox

I have the [Firefly Media Server (mt-daap)](http://www.fireflymediaserver.org/) set up on an Ubuntu 10.10 VM, and I Ubuntu 10.10 set up on my laptop. I am running Rhythmbox and using that to play the music files off the daap share. Unfortunetly, very few of the files play -- Rhythmbox just skips right over them and jumps to the next file. It has occasionally asked me to install a codec, and everytime it has asked I have authorized it to.

Almost all the files are `m4a` files, both the ones that play as well as the ones that don't/ The output of `file` for one that plays is:

> ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, iTunes AAC-LC

The `file` command produces the same output for files which won't play. How can I troubleshoot this further / how can I make Rhythmbox play these other files?

Comment: Just as a start, do you even have the required codecs/decoders installed? It took me a while to figure out that Ubuntu 10.10 couldn't play MP3's out-of-the-box...

Comment: @Blender I'm not sure... how would I check?

Comment: I posted the required package. Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with `mt-daapd` instead of with Rythmbox. I deleted the `mt-daapd` database cache and restarted the server, and after rebuilding the cache all the files now play. I'm sure installing all the software Blender mentioned helped!

Answer (score 4):

Try installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. Ubuntu can't play MP3's and other closed-source encoders (AAC is one of them). You might even have to add a repository, but since I always enable all of those repos, this command worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you don't like the CLI too much, click here to open up Software Installer and do it via a GUI interface: [apt:ubuntu-restricted-extras?section=universe?section=multiverse](http://apt%3aubuntu-restricted-extras?section=universe?section=multiverse).

Good luck!

---

Also, if you're planning to play DVD's too, you might need to install the DVD decoders, as they are not included by default. To do that, run this (no GUI here):

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

---

I'm running out of ideas, but maybe these packages would work? I did some research, and these seemed to fix the problems you're having back in 2007, so the versions might have changed. If you're up to installing more random packages in a frantic attempt to play Apple's ridiculous format, here you go:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad faad libfaad2-0
```

Good luck, once more.

Comment: I <3 the CLI! -- running `apt-get` now, will post back shortly!

Comment: Lol, CLI is always more pleasing that a progress bar. Also, look here for all of the restricted format stuff: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats. The Ubuntu help center is quite useful for quick troubleshooting.

Comment: Sadly I installed that package, but Rhythmbox still skips 95% of the files in my library. :-( I'll check out the link you provided later. Thanks!

Comment: Aww. I'll research some more, and see what I can dig up. Sorry!

Comment: I'm really sorry Blender, this was an issue with `mt-daapd`, not with Rythmbox. I really appreciate all your hard work!